# Surround each line in VS2010 with an html tag

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

I have a list of the 50 states a la

```
Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
```

I would like to wrap each individual line with an anchor tag.  Is this possible to do all at once?  I see that there's a surround with in VS but not for each individual line.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 but any program that could be used would be fine.

So I would like each line to be wrapped something akin to

```
<a href="#" id="stateName">StateName</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at Ala Shibans [Multi Editing Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2beb9705-b568-45d1-8550-751e181e3aef), which allows you to work with multiple cursors at once.

I stole an animated GIF from [Scott Hanselmans Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimultaneousEditingForVisualStudioWithTheFreeMultiEditExtension.aspx):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the values into Column A in a blank spreadsheet
2. Create a formula in cell B1:
   `="<a href=""#"" id=""" & A1 & """>" & A1 & "</a>"`
3. Copy the formula down for each row
4. Copy out the results in column B.